# Adding shapes to Grid in Silverlight with C#

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to add a shape to a Silverlight 5 project in Visual Studio 2012. I have been able to add a shape using XAML, but I would like to do it with C#.

I have tried using example code from [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/rectangle-in-silverlight/).

I have in MainPage.xaml the following line: 
`<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" />`

Then, I have put his CreateARectangle() method in MainPage.xaml.cs. I have put my complete code here: http://pastebin.com/up1NtfE5

I currently get no error upon building. When I launch the page in the browser, it simply circles loading at 100% indefinitely. The plug-in does work, however, as it worked when I tried to make the same object with XAML.

Any help would be appreciated, as well as possibly better resources to accomplish this.

Update: When I switched to debugging with IE instead of Firefox, I got this additional information at the line `LayoutRoot.Children.Add(blueRectangle);`:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call InitializeComponent(); before adding the shapes or it will result in the exception.